Problem calling executable file from ASP.NET website
I'm seeing inconsistent behavior when calling a console application from an ASP.NET web application, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
The C# code, which I modeled after a working web application built by our team, is:
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\MyFolder\\MyProgram.exe";
psi.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\MyFolder";
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

if (System.IO.File.Exists(psi.FileName)
&& System.IO.Directory.Exists(psi.WorkingDirectory))
{
    try
    {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi))
        {
            // This launches the console app
        }

        Label1.Text = "Executable file at " + psi.FileName + " was called.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = psi.FileName + " was not found, or the directory " +
        psi.WorkingDirectory + " does not exist.";
}

The console app named MyProgram.exe should write a simple text file to the folder named MyFolder.  When I run this in Visual Studio in debug mode, it works.  The asp:Label control displays the message that the executable file was called, a pop-up window appears briefly while the executable runs, and the text file appears in MyFolder.
But when I publish the solution to a web server and run it there, it doesn't succeed.  The asp:Label control displays the message that the executable file was called, indicating that the path to MyFolder on the server is valid and the executable file is there, but no pop-up window appears and no text file gets written, suggesting that the executable never runs.
The web server is the same one that our other applications run on with the same permission settings, including some web applications that call executable files using code similar to the C# code shown above.  I can't figure out what is different about my situation.

Essential differences are there, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Well, of course when you run that shell command, then the end user's browser will not see the command window pop up. Remember, when running 100% on your development computer, then the web server and the browser are running on the same computer.
When you publish to the web server, then the shell command window will of course appear on the web server computer - such output does not get sent to the web browser.
So, you see this in the server room:

So, not seeing the console window is correct. That code of course runs on the server, and not the end user's computer running the browser.
So, above shows not seeing the command window is correct, since that shell() command and running the .exe command will of course run on the server, and not your computer with the browser.
Since the command line is running, then this suggests that the web server does not have rights to that given file folder on that other server.
You can test this by manually creating a text file in that folder, and then create a test web test page on your site that checks if that file exists. This will show that the web server does not have permissions to use folders and files outside of the web site and folders within the web site. This almost for sure is your issue.
This means you have to give file and folder permission rights to the "user" that runs code on the web site. Typically, this is iis_user, but in most cases, I suggest creating a user on the web server, and using that for the web site, and then you grant permissions for that user to have rights to the other server folder you are wishing the web server to write out that text file.
You don't mention if you are on a domain, and more important, you don't mention if the web server is part of the domain controller (it probably should not be, but there are differing views on this suggesting).
So, I in most cases suggest creating a user that exists on that web server, and use that user for granting rights to folders.
You then in application pool settings set that new user to be used for all file and code rights on that server under the context of running that web site.
Hence, in application pool settings, you set that user here:

As noted, I don't know if you are using domain logons, but you are thus free to create a new logon with file create and write rights to that other server folder.
Create a button + test code on the web site page to see if it can read files on that external server - that's most likely your issue.
Setting the user in the above application pool means all web server code (code behind) will now run with permissions based on that user set in the application pool. I should point out that this app_pool user has little to do with whatever logon system you are using for the web server.
So, to a test web page, add this test button and code:
Markup:
        <asp:Button ID="cmdTestFile" runat="server" Text="Test for file"
            OnClick="cmdTestFile_Click"
            />

        <asp:Label ID="lblfileTest" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

And code behind:
    protected void cmdTestFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sFile = @"\\server01\testing\text.txt";

        if (File.Exists(sFile))
            lblfileTest.Text = "File does exist";
        else
                lblfileTest.Text = "File does not exist";
        
    }

So, above will test if your web site has file rights to that other server's folder.
Also, keep in mind that code behind uses 100% standard windows file names, and does not require server.mappath().
Only URL's from the markup and web page require translation into a standard windows file name.
So, if you have a folder in the web site called MyFiles?
Then you can use
 sFile = Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/test.txt")

The result of above will be a standard full windows file and path name.
However, unless you map and create a "virtual folder", then a fully qualified windows path name is to be used here. So, unless that folder is a sub folder of the root of the web site then using Server.MapPath() is not required.
So, this line of code:
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\MyFolder";

Is my folder a sub folder of the web site? Or is this a folder to some other location?
And the format for MapPath should be web format using "/".
Hence, above should be:
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/MyFolder");

The above thus assumes you have a sub folder MyFolder in the root of the web site. And it is beyond a bad idea to have and allow .exe files in any of the web sites folders, including the root folder.

Thanks, that explains why I wasn't seeing the pop-up window.
But I'm still not clear on what is preventing execution of the console app.  I don't think it's a permission setting problem, because as I posted, the permissions are the same as for other web apps that aren't having that problem.
I'm not sure what you mean by "this suggests that the web server does not have rights to that given file folder on that other server."  There is no other server.  I'm simply trying to have the console app write a text file to its own folder.  I already do the Exists test, as shown in my post.

Since you stated "it is beyond a bad idea to have and allow .exe files in any of the web sites folders," I'm going to copy the C# code from the console app and paste it into my web app for writing that text file to the folder, and then get rid of the console app.

A fantastic idea, and shell() commands are not all that great in web land anyway. A 100% agree with your design decision. And yes, while you were checking for the existence of the file, I was assuming it always was failing. So, that's why I suggested testing if you can check/test for a existing file. If that never works, then you simply don't have rights to the folder. Possible due to threading with web server, it was never waiting long enough for the shell() to complete (and not debug mode), so code ran too fast and OS had not yet closed up the file.  Moving code into web project = best idea
